# How to get cell value change when closing form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, datagridview

I have a form with a DataGridView on it.

In this DataGridView there is a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn. When changing the value of a cell of this DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, the CellValueChanged-event is only fired when leaving the cell (for example, if I click into another cell).
The event is not fired when I change the value and then just close the form.

So, how can I save the changes (if there are any changes), if my form is simply closed?

**[UPDATE]**

The CellValueChanged is not fired when the form the DataGridView is on is shown through form.ShowDialog():

```
using (FormWithDataGridView form = new FormWithDataGridView()) {
    form.ShowDialog();   // DataGridView on form fires no CellValueChanged-Event when form gets closed
}
```

Comment: I tried it, the CellValueChanged even has fired when I closed the form !, could you retry it and ensure that you're changing the original value.

Comment: Funny: I created a small project, copied my DataGridView-initialisation-code and CellValueChanged event is fired, too. But not in my real application... ?-|

Comment: Is the event fired when you stop editing the cell? I mean if you choose a value, then fire the EndEdit event (or something like that) would it work? If so, then you could, on form close, check if you're in editmode, then if so, endedit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the community content post on the MSDN entry for [ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog%28de-de,VS.90%29.aspx), when you close a modal form, it is just being hidden so the calling code can still have access to the `DialogResult` or other properties of the form.  Apparently, this is why the `CellValueChanged` event on the `DataGridView` is not firing (`CellParsing` and `CellEndEdit` events also do not get raised).

As a workaround, in the form closing event, you can remove focus from the `DataGridView`, which will cause the `CellValueChanged` event to fire if necessary.  If you don't have any other controls on the form to set focus to, you can put a label on the form and give it focus.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using `dataGridView1.CellParsing`? This should (as I understand it) trigger even if the focus of the cell is lost due to closing the containing Form. This will only trigger if the user has changed the value of the cell.

[Edit] Now when I think about it a bit more I would try `dataGridView1.CellEndEdit` if I was you. That is better..[/Edit]

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar situation myself, but with the last checkbox updated programmatically--whouldn't update unless I switched rows.

Try calling the BindingSource.EndEdit method just before you update the combobox.

For me I call the data adapter afterwards and it recognizes a change to the datagridview--so it does the work.